# await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() returns an empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

First of all

```
var myString = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

should always work. But it doesn't. Here we go:

**AirplaneController.cs**

```
[ValidateAirplane]
[HydrateAirplane]
public class AirplaneController : ApiController
```

**ValidateAirplane.cs (see the amazing magic line)**

```
public class ValidateAirplaneAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilterpublic class ValidateAirplaneAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
...
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    var json = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // <-- amazing magic line
    return await continuation();
}
```

**HydrateAirplane.cs**

```
public class HydrateAirplaneAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
...
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    var json = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return await continuation();
}
```

If I comment out the `amazing magic line` then `json` in `ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync` comes back as an empty string. However if I don't comment out the `amazing magic line` I get the json (the airplane JSON that came from the client).

At first I thought this might be a timing issue so I tried doing a `await Task.Delay(5000)` in `HydrateAirplane.cs` just before trying to read the json but it has no effect.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Do you need to reset the position of the stream first?

Comment: I expect json to be a non-empty string. Specifically, it should be the JSON sent from the client. I'm not actually sure what `continuation()` does but you have to return it like that to get the method to work.

Comment: @Julian omg that's a good idea! Sadly no, lol. The problem is actually the opposite of that. It only shows up in the second filter if I read it in the first filter.

Comment: @RyanWilson they are different filters that perform different functions which is why the code is duplicated. `myString` was just an example at the top of the question. The question is I don't understand why doing `actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` in the first filter has and effect on doing `actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` in the second filter. If doing it in the first filter stopped it from working in the second filter that might make sense. But doing it in the first filter is what makes it work in the second filter and that is doubly confusing to me.

Comment: @user875234 I think this has something to do with the calling thread being able to execute on the call to `await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); ` in the AuthorizationFilter class allowing for the ExecuteActionFilter to be called and the response still has a value in Content, when taking that line away, it awaits continuation() which must allow for some other thread to clear the content of the request before the calling thread can call the ExecuteActionFilter. (This is just a guess), would be nice if someone could give a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a work around than an answer. If you have a better answer please share. I noticed there's a `ReadAsStreamAsync` and I was able to get that to work. Maybe this is a bug in WebAPI? I couldn't find the code on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/tree/master/src) so I don't know for sure. My work around is to use this extension method instead of `ReadAsStringAsync`:

```
public async static Task<string> GetRequestBody(this HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var bodyStream = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    bodyStream.Position = 0;

    var bytes = new byte[bodyStream.Length];
    await bodyStream.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    bodyStream.Position = 0; // <-- i don't know why but this line is important. it doesn't work on subsequent calls without this. ...to be clear, it absolutely should work. i consider this to be a WebAPI work around. that is, i should not have to ever even think about this.

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
}
```

The reason this isn't wrapped in a using is it was wrapped in a using but then WebAPI started throwing a stream is not readable error which I guess means they use the exact same stream that they return to you internally.